# Standard behavior for C-x in CUA mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I recently switched from `vi` to `emacs`. I like `CUA` mode. However, `CUA` mode makes `C-x` kill the active region. This is annoying when I want to, say, clear a rectangular selection with `C-x r c`.

How can I use `CUA` mode while having completely out-of-the-box behavior for `C-x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cua-selection-mode` instead of `cua-mode`.

The former provides CUA's other configuration and facilities (for example the rectangle editing mentioned by Francesco), but it leaves <kbd>C-x</kbd>, <kbd>C-c</kbd>, <kbd>C-v</kbd>, and <kbd>C-z</kbd> alone, meaning that it's highly compatible with out-of-the-box Emacs usage.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the help for cua-mode it gives you options for using commands which conflict with the prefix keys (like <kbd>C-x</kbd>):

```
If you really need to perform a command which starts with one of
the prefix keys even when the region is active, you have three
options:
- press the prefix key twice very quickly (within 0.2 seconds),
- press the prefix key and the following key within 0.2 seconds, or
- use the SHIFT key with the prefix key, i.e. C-S-x or C-S-c.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to jtahlborn's general answer, please also note that cua-mode reimplements rectangular commands (IMHO in a much fancier way than the standard <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> commands)

Just press <kbd>C-RET</kbd> to enter rectangular selection mode. From there regular commands work on the rectangular selection: you can for example delete the region using <kbd>DEL</kbd>.